# Recursive parse JSON with c#

Tags: c#, json, parsing, recursion

I try to do a recursive parse but it doesn't work, it only parse the first title.

I already tried that: [C# parse recursive json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49923676/c-sharp-parse-recursive-json) but it didn't work.

I also tried a parse with Regex but it didn't work either, it only captures the first title.

So I'm hoping you can help me solve the problem that's been blocking my progress :/

My Json

```
{ 
   "data":{ 
      "count":[ 

      ],
      "list":[ 
         { 
            "title":"new doc 4",
            "rotate":0,
            "sort_key":"new doc 4",
            "tag_ids":"",
            "doc_id":"ee4DM4Ly7CFBM3JFWAW60TUX",
            "co_token":"",
            "p":"XQXLDEQyA2hf6BBfyXhSaUHL",
            "t":"1474932063",
            "c":"2",
            "updated":"1474932063"
         },
         { 
            "title":"new doc 5",
            "rotate":0,
            "sort_key":"new doc 5",
            "tag_ids":"",
            "doc_id":"Xy67QdRhTR9XS159WLyCCTbK",
            "co_token":"",
            "p":"XadS23UUQbQRQt9gLPWDWTAQ",
            "t":"1474932060",
            "c":"1",
            "updated":"1474932061"
         },
         { 
            "title":"new doc 6",
            "rotate":0,
            "sort_key":"new doc 6",
            "tag_ids":"",
            "doc_id":"Q4W55XLA1AeERUJHaVN7EF80",
            "co_token":"",
            "p":"T6BYAMKXNa086Tb4FaYd4rV1",
            "t":"1474932059",
            "c":"1",
            "updated":"1474932059"
         },
         { 
            "title":"new doc 7",
            "rotate":0,
            "sort_key":"new doc 7",
            "tag_ids":"",
            "doc_id":"9heQFfeYFUFXb536VTyHLhKL",
            "co_token":"",
            "p":"BeFULN12QL6H9L5HXCAYfH1S",
            "t":"1474932056",
            "c":"2",
            "updated":"1474932056"
         },
         { 
            "title":"new doc 8",
            "rotate":0,
            "sort_key":"new doc 8",
            "tag_ids":"",
            "doc_id":"H7eXd1yTfFAY2V8ha3a6FS9K",
            "co_token":"",
            "p":"LJVyNVCPMbXH2abMMbb6BRYN",
            "t":"1474932053",
            "c":"1",
            "updated":"1474932053"
         },
         { 
            "title":"new doc 9",
            "rotate":0,
            "sort_key":"new doc 9",
            "tag_ids":"",
            "doc_id":"3VVL56tQDXf73V8UKXrNX0d0",
            "co_token":"",
            "p":"rV2H7WWCRy1Vrb0PaU1TQKTD",
            "t":"1474932047",
            "c":"3",
            "updated":"1474932049"
         },
         { 
            "title":"new doc 10",
            "rotate":0,
            "sort_key":"new doc 10",
            "tag_ids":"",
            "doc_id":"4TBabHAKNRXdREJXNdWfQEWF",
            "co_token":"",
            "p":"TR7Dt89gV3hfSJBTDQ1JQP72",
            "t":"1474402937",
            "c":"1",
            "updated":"1474402937"
         },
         { 
            "title":"new doc 11",
            "rotate":0,
            "sort_key":"new doc 11",
            "tag_ids":"",
            "doc_id":"TV4fBdehY4fFHN00g082QDKX",
            "co_token":"",
            "p":"SCUPQ9bW6BgTT9JAP4K2WCYU",
            "t":"1474402932",
            "c":"3",
            "updated":"1474402932"
         },
         { 
            "title":"new doc 12",
            "rotate":0,
            "sort_key":"new doc 12",
            "tag_ids":"",
            "doc_id":"M8fHK8gQB3FWUEeLKQMdUaFB",
            "co_token":"",
            "p":"BPDTg3aTTDELyFUA1WK0M2rA",
            "t":"1474402911",
            "c":"7",
            "updated":"1474402913"
         },
         { 
            "title":"new doc",
            "rotate":0,
            "sort_key":"new doc",
            "tag_ids":"",
            "doc_id":"ayCK8RrHSe796g4PSNRgMD5N",
            "co_token":"",
            "p":"Y46RWJFb0XJRHtKy6B077Me1",
            "t":"1389379718",
            "c":"1",
            "updated":"1389379718"
         }
      ],
   }
}
```

Comment: You do not have recursion.  This looks like just a List.

Comment: Your json doesnt have anything that would require you to do anything recursive... `JObject.Parse(json)` will take care of deserialization. Also, please do explain how you intend to use this json once parsed

Comment: I want to add the titles in a text file

Comment: I don't understand how : JObject.Parse(json) can help me get the titles back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Parse the string into an object that c# can use to iterate through.
2. then use the foreach loop to access the items of the list.
3. Add title to a stringbuilder
4. Save the collected titles to a file.

```
var obj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
var list = obj["data"]["list"];

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(var item in list)
    sb.AppendLine(item["title"].ToString());

File.WriteAllText(@"c:\temp\titles.txt", sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Error on sb.ToString();

C# Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'string[]'

Comment: Use WriteAllText instead of lines.

Answer (score 0):

I used Newtonsoft.Json package to convert json from file data.json which contains the json data

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        LoadJson();
    }

    public static void LoadJson()
    {
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"C:\\Users\\user\\source\\repos\\RecursiveParseJSON\\RecursiveParseJSON\\data.json")) 
        {
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();
            JsonObject datas = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonObject>(json);
        }
    }
}


public class JsonObject
{
    public Data data { get; set; }
}
public class Data
{
    public List<string> count { get; set; }
    public List<Doc> list { get; set; }
}

public class Doc
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public int rotate { get; set; }
    public string sort_key { get; set; }
    public string tag_ids { get; set; }
    public string doc_id { get; set; }
    public string co_token { get; set; }
    public string p { get; set; }
    public string t { get; set; }
    public string c { get; set; }
    public string updated { get; set; }
}
```